# Where does the network configuration file reside on a Pi and how can change it programmatically?

Tags: python, file, system

I am trying to learn Python and Linux at the same time. I need to be able to change the network configuration, via Python program, and make it stick for future boots.

I see a lot of conflicting info on the net and I am not truly seeing what I am looking for.
1) Where do the network configuration files reside, IP address, DNS, DHCP vs static, etc... and what are their names?
2) How can I change them programmatically, since, being system files,  permissions are involved?

Comment: The files most probably reside in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` and would require superuser permissions. This is only tangentially python and might well be better off on SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: "The network configuration" is also not a well-defined entity. Do you want to change how the network cards are set up, which name servers to use, which interfaces should receive which numbers, firewalls, services, what?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question partly depends on which distribution you're running.  Using Raspbian, which is Debian-based, you will find network configuraiton in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and in files contained in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`.  RedHat derived systems like Fedora will store configuration files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`.  Your distribution documentation should have details about the file formats.

These are simple text files, so if you're looking to manipulate them programatically you could write a simple parser.

If your system is running NetworkManager, you have an actual DBUS API that can be use to manipulate your network configuration.  You can find details of that API [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/Developers#D-Bus_API_Documentation_and_Examples).  There are Python bindings available for dbus and for Gobject that you can use to interact with NetworkManager.

You will generally need to be running as `root` to make changes to these files directly.  Using NetworkManager you may have more flexible authorization options available, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Nice. Thank you.